# Chrome Export Html table to Excel

Tags: excel, google-chrome, templates, export

I have a Excel template placed on the server. I need to copy the html table content into the
template when user click on export to excel. I have the below code what this does is it generates it own excel instead copying the data into the template.I am using javascript for this.I code needs to be compatible with chrome I have it working for IE.Please help

```
$( "#Export" ).click(function() {  
    var location = document.createElement('a');

    var url =('data:application/vnd.ms-excel, ' +  encodeURIComponent($('#MyTable').html()) 
    location.href= url
    location.click();

});
```

Now where do I add my excel template path so that content of "MyTable" gets pasted on the excel template. Please suggest only JavaScript and no supporting files required

Comment: Are you saying the code you posted works in IE?

Comment: I have code for IE I just want the above code to work in Chrome with excel template from server

Comment: Can you post the client-side HTML table content to the server and populate the template server-side?  Not sure how else you would do this.  How are you doing it with IE - are you automating Excel client-side?

Comment: I am using window.clipboard.setData to copy the data into the excel in IE but in Chrome window.clipboard.setData doesn't work

Comment: If you post the code which works in IE, someone might suggest a fix for Chrome...

Comment: The code for IE uses window.open and window.clipboard.setData these function doesn't work in Chrome.SO please suggest for the function given above.